# Where to place sdk.txt file for previously installed Android SDK?

Tags: android, sdk, renpy

It is said in `renpy` documentation and I quote:

> If you don't want to download the SDK each time, you can create a file named sdk.txt containing a single line that is the path to the already-installed SDK

The problem is that, after I create the file with the content going to the Android SDK parent path, the `renpy` GUI Android still needs to download Android SDK(did not see the pre-installed Android SDK). I cannot access the configuration button when it cannot see the Android SDK installed path.

Note: I checked the Android SDK path and it is correct. `D:\android-sdk\`

Answer (score 0):

Go inside the folder where you installed RenPy (*not* the project folder!).

There you will see another folder called `rapt`. You need to save the `sdk.txt` inside that folder.

```
├── LICENSE.txt
├── doc
├── gui
├── launcher
├── lib
├── log.txt
├── module
├── rapt    <- Add sdk.txt here
├── renpy
├── renpy.app
├── renpy.exe
├── renpy.py
├── renpy.sh
├── sdk-fonts
├── the_question
├── tmp
├── traceback.txt
├── tutorial
└── update
```

If you don't see the `rapt` folder, RenPy will probably create that for you automatically when it asks you to install the RAPT tool.

You might have to restart RenPy for it to reflect within the app.